# trying to format a 64GB MicroSDXC card with 4096 bytes per sector

Tags: 16.04, fat32

I'm trying to flash Rockbox onto an xDuoo digital music player, and the micro SD card has to be formatted FAT32 with 4096 bytes per sector. I've come across conflicting reports for mkdosfs parameters, can someone help me (stabs in the dark have not worked yet)?

Comment: "Conflicting reports"? Read `man mkdosfs` ( http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mkdosfs.8.html ) for the truth.

Answer (score 2):

The manual `man mkfs.fat` suggests the option `-S`

> -S LOGICAL-SECTOR-SIZE
>
> Specify the number of bytes per logical sector.  Must be a power of 2
>   and greater  than  or equal to 512, i.e. 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, or 32768.

**Before running the command, please double-check, that you will format the correct partition, and not a partition with valuable data.**

I hope this will work for you,

- if connected via USB

  ```
  sudo mkfs.fat -S 4096 /dev/sdxn
  ```

  where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, or
- if connected via PCI

  ```
  sudo mkfs.fat -S 4096 /dev/mmcblkmpn
  ```

  where m is the device number (probably 0) and n is the partition number.

You will find how the card is connected via the following commands

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m

sudo parted -ls
```

---

Check the sector size with for example

```
sudo fsck.fat -v /dev/sdxn
```

Some other tools may not show the sector size of the FAT file system. The important thing is that it will work for your application.

**Example:** I had the following result

```
$ sudo mkfs.fat -S 4096 /dev/sdd1
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)

$ sudo fsck.fat -v /dev/sdd1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
      4096 bytes per logical sector
     65536 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 131072 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
    978944 bytes per FAT (= 239 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 2088960 (sector 510)
    244304 data clusters (16010706944 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 64 heads
      2048 hidden sectors
   3909376 sectors total
Checking for unused clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
/dev/sdd1: 0 files, 1/244304 clusters
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something else involved with the Xduoo X3 player recognizing the card. I tried a dozen times using the card formatted under Linux without success (using the excellent and detailed solution described by sudodos) -- finally, I used the method recommended by Windows users, a formatting utility called "guiformat.exe," under my old VirtualBox XP installation, and it worked.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)